# SQL: show elements that either don't exist in another table, or that exist but without a row with a specific value in one of the columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i want a query that shows all the jobs (EmpNo,JobNo,JobName) that a candidate DIDN'T apply to yet (meaning that job either doesn't exist in tblJobApplications, or exist, but this user didn't apply to it). current candidate's ID is stored in the module as Get_Login() that returns string. (several candidates can apply to a single job, so if one of those rows contains candidate's id, the entire job's rows are discarded from result).

given:

```
tblJobs:
* EmpNo (long)
* JobNo (long)
  JobName (string)

tblJobApplications:
* EmpNo (long)
* JobNo (long)
* Id_candidate (string)

public function Get_Login() as String  (returns current user's id)
```

example:

```
tblJobs:
1, 1, Coach
1, 2, Trainer
2, 3, Gardner

tblJobApplications:
1, 2, currentuser
1, 2, 23917283
2, 3, 94718233

in this situation, the result should show:
1, 1, Coach
2, 3, Gardner
```

my sql knowledge is very limited at this point.
i was thinking that first i should make a query that fetches all of current user's job applications (to get the EmpNo, JobNo 's that i should discard) and than somehow remove them from the result of a simple query that shows all jobs.

Comment: You should really include more information What did you try, what is the problem you have. Some sample data and result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the data structure correctly, then a `not exists` query should work:

```
select j.*
from tbljobs as j
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblApplications as a
                  where a.jobNo = j.jobNo and
                        a.id_candidate = get_login()
                 );
```

Comment: thank you very much!  helped me a lot... you forgot the other EmpNo key in the where clause... and eventually needed a group by. but very close to what you wrote.